# Remount an SSHFS mount without umounting it

Tags: mount, sshfs, fuse

What is the equivalent to `mount -o remount,ro` in an `sshfs` mount?

The only way I know is to do `fusermount -u` and then mount it again with `sshfs -o ro`.

Answer (score 2):

FUSE doesn't have any generic support for the `remount` option. In 2006 with FUSE 2.6 this was described as impossible to do for a FUSE-based filesystem without patching FUSE itself ([fuse-devel thread “Remounting in FUSE support”](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/mailman/message/9996780/)). There doesn't seem to have been any progress since then.

There are requests for remount support in SSHFS (e.g. [Ubuntu bug #1037500](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sshfs-fuse/+bug/1037500)) and other FUSE filesystems around the web, none fulfilled that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the generic answer about FUSE. I was searching this information for my own fuse filesystem development.

I guess the next best answer is that the fuse filesystem supports the feature itself. The filesystem will continue to receive "write-related" kernel requests and has to respond with the appropriate error code, for instance: EROFS for "create".

From the user perspective, that would behave exactly as if the flesystem were read-only, with the slight difference that is does not say so when looking at mounts.

The feature could be "automagically" triggered by errors. The tricky part is if the user wants to trigger it since remount is not an option, or worse, FUSE will tell that the mountpoint is non-empty.
The filesystem must then expose a non-standard method to shift to "faked-readonly", for example doing `touch /mountpoint/.read_only`

So the answer could be: it is not possible the standard way. The fuse filesystem could support a similar feature by exposing a method to get the equivalent functionality.